# Different Implementation of the same JS program in C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I recently raised a question about implementing sieve of eratosthenes in Javascript on SO and here's the working answer I got:

```
function sieve(low, high) {
var primeArray = [], ll = Math.sqrt(high), output = [];

for (var i = 2; i <= high; i++) {
    primeArray[i] = true;
}

for (var i = 2; i <= ll; i++) {
    if (primeArray[i]) {
        for (var j = i * i; j <= high; j += i) {
            primeArray[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 2; i <= ll; i++) {
    if(primeArray[i]) {
        var segmentStart = Math.ceil(low/i) * i;
        // need this test to ensure we are not deleting primes
        if (primeArray[segmentStart]) segmentStart += i; 

        for(var j = segmentStart; j <= high; j+=i) {
            primeArray[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

for(var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    if(primeArray[i]) {
        output.push(i);
    }
}
return output;
}

console.log(sieve(1, 20));
```

I tried implementing the same in C++ 
However the end result is quite different.
My C++ program is somehow ignoring the first 2 prime numbers while maintaining 1 as a prime.

Here's the same program in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int low, high;
cout << "Enter lower bound: ";
cin >> low;
cout << "Enter upper bound: ";
cin >> high;

int root = floor(sqrt(high));
int primes[high];

for(int i = 2; i <= high; i++)
{
    primes[i] = true;
}

for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
    if (primes[i]) {
        for (int j = i * i; j <= high; j += i) {
            primes[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
    if(primes[i]) {
        int segmentStart = ceil(low/i) * i;

        if (primes[segmentStart]) segmentStart += i;

        for(int j = segmentStart; j <= high; j+=i) {
            primes[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

for(int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    if(primes[i]) {
        cout << i;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

`low/i` division operation in `int segmentStart = ceil(low/i) * i;` was returning an integer and hence it was ignoring results < 1;

I typecasted i as a double to solve this problem like this:

`int segmentStart = ceil(low/(double)i) * i;`